# Trying to figure out a way to prompt the user for a integer or character at the same time and accept the input for either a character or integer

Tags: c, input, output

```
int main ()
{

    float num1=0,num2=0,total=1,sum,a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0;  
    scanf("%f",&a);
    scanf("%f",&b);
    printf("Please enter the first number or variable:\n");
        //store in num1
    //I assume some type of function to calculate 
    printf("//whatever the user imputed whether it be the value stored in a or the value stored in num1)
}
```

This is a trimmed portion of my code, but the purpose is here
I'm coding in c and was trying to figure out how to determine whether the user entered a variable or a integer value.

Comment: You need to read a string and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure based on your code, but based on the wording of your question you want to get one character and determine if it is a character or a digit? You can use the is functions in ctype.h to determine what the input is, for example:

```
int ch = fgetc(stdin);

if(isdigit(ch)) {
    printf("integer\n");
} else {
    if(isalpha(ch)) {
        printf("character\n");
    } else {
        printf("something else\n");
    }
}
```